# Changing options_for_select from data returned from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to write a function to change my options_for_select tag (for user's vendors) after the user creates a new vendor:

```
$("#newVendor-from-inventory-form").on("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status) {
  var newOptions = data;
  var $el = $("#inventory_vendor_id");
  $el.empty(); // remove old options
  _.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
     $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
  });
});
```

Here is an example of what is stored in `newOptions` or `data`:

```
[["Test",1],["New Vendor",18],["2",19],["1",20],["asdf",21],["fd",22],["adf",23]]
```

The problem right now is that when I iterate through `newOptions`, it is iterating through `newOptions` as if it were a string. So if I `console.log(key)`, I would get each individual character. I want my key to be the first value (e.g. "Test" or "New Vendor") and for the id to be returned (e.g. 1 or 18).

How do I correctly change my options for my `options_for_select` tag? I assume there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In the rails form, I just had to pass `html: {:'data-type' => 'json'}` for the data type to be interpreted as json instead of as a string

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at jquery, but here is my solution

```
for( var i = 0; i < newOptions.length; i++ ) {
   $("#inventory_vendor_id").append( $('<option value="'+ newOptions[i][0] +'">'+ newOptions[i][1] +'</option>') );
}
```